# Why this object accelerates?? setInterval not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I make a player in game and i can't do move method. When I click D button player moves 10px, next D click player moves for example 33px;
I don't know why

```
function Player(){
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;

    this.Move = function(){
        window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
            switch (event.keyCode) {
              case 87: //W
                console.log("w");
                break;
              case 83: //S
                break;
              case 65: //A
                x--;
                break;
              case 68: //D
                x++;
                break;
            }
          }, true);
    }
    this.Draw = function(){
        ctx.fillStyle="color:white";
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,80,80);
    }
}

setInterval(GameLoop,(1000/60));
```

Comment: What is `GameLoop`?

Comment: gameLoop is a function which contains player.draw();

Comment: It should be Player as first argument of your setInterval.

Comment: Does it contain `player.Move()` also? Thus adding another key event handler every time the interval fires?

Comment: how is Move called? So many unknowns with this code. My guess you bind that event handler over and over again.

Comment: It also contains player.move

Comment: Every time you call `player.move()` you increase the number of times the `keydown` listener runs when the user presses a key.

Comment: You need to define the handler for the keydown event outside of `Move`.

Comment: You should just add the listener once, not every time the player moves.

Comment: ok give me a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `Move` first, then set it as the handler for the keydown event, so that a new handler will not be created for each interval.

```js
function Player(){
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;

    this.Move = function(event){
        switch (event.keyCode) {
              case 87: //W
                console.log("w");
                break;
              case 83: //S
                break;
              case 65: //A
                x--;
                break;
              case 68: //D
                x++;
                break;
            }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this.Move, true);
    
    this.Draw = function(){
        ctx.fillStyle="color:white";
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,80,80);
    }
}

setInterval(GameLoop,(1000/60));
```